# Which is better for a background service WakeLock or startForeground

Tags: android

Admittedly I am just kind of hacking here so I would like some knowledge.

I have a service I run in the background connected to another thread that counts down a timer. I was having problems with the count down dying after a while and presumed it was due to garbage collection of the service. I seem to have fixed the issue (and see no real battery use) using startForeground. Now I read about wakelocks, are there any best practices on when to use one or the other?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have a service I run in the background connected to another thread that counts down a timer.

Please use `AlarmManager`, so your service only needs to be in memory when it is actually doing work, not just watching the clock tick. One of the biggest user complaints about Android is all these background things that developers create that clog up their phones.

> I seem to have fixed the issue (and see no real battery use) using startForeground.

The point behind `startForeground()` is to indicate that your service is continuously delivering value to the user, such that the user will notice if the service is reclaimed due to hanging around too long or low memory conditions. Sitting and watching the clock tick is *not* "continuously delivering value to the user". Please use `AlarmManager`, and you will not need `startForeground()`.

> Now I read about wakelocks, are there any best practices on when to use one or the other?

`WakeLock` keeps the CPU powered on (and possibly other things, like the screen). It has little to do with `startForeground()`. If you use `AlarmManager`, depending on the work that you are doing, you may need a `WakeLock` to ensure the device stays awake while you do your perodic wo

Comment: "The point behind startForeground() is to indicate that your service is continuously delivering value to the user, such that the user will notice if the service is reclaimed due to hanging around too long or low memory conditions. Sitting and watching the clock tick is not "continuously delivering value to the user". Please use AlarmManager, and you will not need startForeground()."  Right but it is, I am registering hits from the accelerometer at the same time and reseting the clock each time I get a reading. So I do need it open at the same time. I will look into Alarm Manager.

Comment: @Jackie: "I am registering hits from the accelerometer at the same time at the same time and reseting the clock each time I get a reading" -- it is unclear why this is a service at all. The device has to be powered on at all times when trying to use the sensors. The sensors are designed to be used from the foreground activity. Regardless, `AlarmManager` will not help you here. You will, however, need a `WakeLock` if you want to prevent the device from falling asleep so you can read your sensors.

Comment: "The device has to be powered on at all times when trying to use the sensors." I don't believe this is true, because if it was I would think I would be seeing more battery drain. It seems to work fine for now.

Comment: @Jackie: You assume all devices are the same. Particularly with regards to sensors, you are mistaken, based upon the loud and numerous complaints from other developers on this topic. Again, sensors are designed to be used by a foreground activity, not a background service.