# How to use AlarmManager Inside a Service without using PendingIntent?

Tags: android, service, alarmmanager

Excuse me, I have a question please.

I want to create a service to start once the the device is up and running by extending BroadcastReceiver. Inside the service class, I want to initiate an alarm manager to display a notification after certain time. Then, once the time is elapsed the notification is displayed, the alarm manger should be rescheduled for the next specified time. How could achieve that as alarm manager set function requires pending intent where no pending intent is required as I am inside a service class. I insist on using alarm manager instead of Timer as the following link suggests using it: [Which is better for a background service WakeLock or startForeground](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8038967/which-is-better-for-a-background-service-wakelock-or-startforeground)

The code:

```
public class BootCompletedReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    final static String TAG = "BootCompletedReceiver";

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent arg1) {
        Log.w(TAG, "starting service...");
        context.startService(new Intent(context, BookkeeperService.class));
    }
}
```

---

```
import android.app.AlarmManager;
import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.os.PowerManager;

public class BookkeeperService extends Service {
    AlarmManager alarmManager;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(){
        super.onCreate();

        alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
        // here I need to set the alarm to notify the user after certain time and then reschedule 
        // to the next event
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);

        return START_NOT_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Thank you

Comment: Your statement "no pending intent is required as I am inside a service class" makes no sense. Please clarify. Also you can  have a Service extend a Broadcast Receiever.. this is confusing keep your code clean.

Comment: Sorry, meant, as I need to show a notification only, I do not need a pending intent.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pass messages through a Alarm to Broadcast Reciever, just have the Alarm dispatch a message at your leisure and then have that start your registration for more alarm(s). You can start the Alarm from your service and from there have the Alarms maintain themselves.